# normalize strings of a column with fuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a df similar to this (this is just an example, original df in spanish and is cumbersome to copy paste an excerpt here):

```
date          city1  city2      ID    company 
01-10-2020   Mexico  Mexico    1234   ColaCola
03-01-2020   Mexico  Baja      567    Cola cola
02-09-2020   Mexico  Culiacan  8900   Cola Cola Inc.
03-04-2020   Mexico  Tulum     2344   Cola Cola Inc
06-07-2020   Mexico  Ver       3459   Cola cola inc
```

so, i need to have all those variations of company's name under same one:

```
    date          city1  city2      ID    company 
    01-10-2020   Mexico  Mexico    1234   Cola Cola
    03-01-2020   Mexico  Baja      567    Cola Cola
    02-09-2020   Mexico  Culiacan  8900   Cola Cola 
    03-04-2020   Mexico  Tulum     2344   Cola Cola 
    06-07-2020   Mexico  Ver       3459   Cola Cola
```

I tried using:

```
df['company'].str.replace({'ColaCola': 'Cola Cola', 'Cola cola':'Cola Cola'})
```

and so on. The problem was, there are a lot of variations on company's name (original is way longer): capital/not capital letters, spaces, typos, periods, spaces...you name it! To do it manually it would take me hours.
So, I needed a better way to do this. Then I came across wuzzyfuzzy. But I cant get past the examples. I don't really get it.

I think something like this could work:

```
for row in df.company:
      fuzz.partial_ratio("Cola Cola": "str.row")
    if fuzz.partial_ratio >= 90:
    "str.row" = "Cola Cola"
```

or something like this. Excuse me, I have never been able to use rightly loops. Please help me.

Comment: Do you know how many unique companies your DataFrame has (i.e. you know there should be Coca Cola, Nabisco, Hasbro, Johnson & Johnson, with all their different representations) or do you have no idea and need a way to programmatically cluster similar company names? The latter can be extremely complicated.

Comment: I have 50 unique companies. Yes, to do them all at once it would be hard (and event this I dont know how to do it)

Answer (score 0):

```py
obj = df['company']

# have a look at `company`
obj.value_counts().sort_index()

# use regexp and find the common part in regexp
cond = obj.str.contains('cola\s*cola', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df.loc[cond, 'NAME_new'] = 'Cola Cola'
...
# find the other company name's common & unique part and rename it

print(df)

0        date   city1     city2    ID         company   NAME_new
1  01-10-2020  Mexico    Mexico  1234        ColaCola  Cola Cola
2  03-01-2020  Mexico      Baja   567       Cola cola  Cola Cola
3  02-09-2020  Mexico  Culiacan  8900  Cola Cola Inc.  Cola Cola
4  03-04-2020  Mexico     Tulum  2344   Cola Cola Inc  Cola Cola
5  06-07-2020  Mexico       Ver  3459   Cola cola inc  Cola Cola
```